# Cannot include project artifact: com.test.mmm.jar:1.0; it doesn't have an associated file or directory

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm pretty lost with maven and I can't seem to find a solution for my problem. When I try to generate the jar file with all the dependencies of my project to execute it on another computer I find this warning when I execute `sudo mvn clean compile assembly:single`:

```
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.test:mmm:jar:1.0; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
```

Also, when I try to execute the .jar with `java -jar target/test.jar` this error appears:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile target/test.jar
```

here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>mmm</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>mmm</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <nd4j.backend>nd4j-cuda-8.0-platform</nd4j.backend>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jblas</groupId>
        <artifactId>jblas</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.test.mmm.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
                <descriptorRefs>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The main class is located in `src/`
I've tried many solutions from stack overflow but had no success, can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Use `mvn package` first to build your module classes then `assembly:single`.

`mvn package assembly:single`

Comment: Is there a reason for this?

Comment: An artifact first need to be generated, as the Assembly plugin doc states: 
```(provided all required files are available before the build starts, or are produced by another goal specified before this one on the command line)``` https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#assembly-single

Answer (score 3):

From the warning you've included in your question:

`[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: Amjar:amjar:pom:0.2; it doesn't have an associated`.
I'd guess that you've got the packaging in your `pom.xml` set to pom.

This is fine if your module is simply packaging a set of dependencies or resource files, however, if you also want Maven to create a jar containing the classes in you module you will need to set the packaging to jar.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your atrifact produced is matching with `<finalName>`
i.e.

```
<groupId>com.rocket</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>myapp</name>
```

produces myapp-1.0.jar
and provide same here

```
<finalName>myapp-1.0</finalName>
```

and run then execute:

```
mvn package assembly:single
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it might help someone else that ends up here like I did:

I just had that same warning about `[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact:`. It followed from the maven-assembly-plugin just refusing to bind to the `mvn package` execution phase so I started trying to run it "manually" with `mvn assembly:single`. It turns out you have to include `package` and `asssembly:single` in the same `mvn` command line, like so:

```
mvn package assembly:single
```

If you run first `mvn package` and then `mvn assembly:single` then the assembly plugin won't find your regular jar to include although it's there in your target folder. The assembly plugin's `mvn -X` output even explicitly says it's the jar in my target folder it's using when assembling my jar-with-dependencies, but if it's created by a previous mvn run it won't find it. Smells buggy to me and cost me well over an hour to figure out.